# SAQL - Unnest Array to Rows

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

Is there a way using SAQL to unnest an array into multiple rows?

For example, my output is

`['abc', 'def', ghi']`

and I would like to end up with

`'abc'`
`'def'`
`'ghi'`